# Parallax-Animation Scrolling Effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I've been wanting to implement a similar effect like in these apple sites where the computer animation changes with the scroll.

https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/
https://www.apple.com/imac-pro/

Searching around how to implement the sort of parallax effect Apple does in these websites, I haven't expressly found something quite the same, how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They propbaly used `three.js` scripts to achive this. But you can do it in much more easier way but with worse performace for sure. You need to make a lot of photos (you know like in the movie frame by frame) and then on the scroll event you have to replace photo with prevoius one(if you detect scroll top) or with next one (if you detect scroll down). If you detect last or first item then you stop hijacking scroll event and let browser do the job.

If you want to learn more abot **three.js** you can read more about this here: [three.js - Learn](https://threejs.org/)

In the end of `<body></body>` element of [this website](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/) you can see that they added **three.js** :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also researching what apple use on their website and found out that a tool called Lottie.

Lotttie is a design library by Airbnb you can find it [here](https://airbnb.design/lottie/)
[image]

"Lottie is an iOS, Android, and React Native library that renders After Effects animations in real-time, allowing apps to use animations as easily as they use static images."
Lottie also has a web version available [here](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web)